# Please level all columns (2nd and 3rd Columns Broken).

Tags: html, css

Please see preview of my pasted pricing table code below. Then you will see 2nd and 3rd columns are broken to down. All columns are not in same levels. Please fix my code and level all 3 columns.

See codes below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu);
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Ubuntu, arial, verdana;
}
.pricing_table {
    line-height: 150%;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500%;
    max-width: 800px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.price_block {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    transition: all 0.25s;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.pricing_table h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background: #A6DA18;
    margin: -10px 0 1px 0;
}

.price {
    display: table;
    background: #444;
float: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
}
.price_figure {
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
.price_number {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}
.price_tenure {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.features {
    background: #DEF0F4;
    color: #000;
}
.features li {
    padding: 8px 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 11px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.footer {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #DEF0F4;
}
.action_button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(#666, #333);
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.price_block:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transform: scale(1.04) translateY(-5px);
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
}
.price_block:hover .price {
    background:linear-gradient(#DB7224, #F9B84A);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 45px 1px #DB7224;
}
.price_block:hover h3 {
    background: #222;
}
.price_block:hover .action_button {
    background: linear-gradient(#F9B84A, #DB7224);
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 768px) {
    .price_block {width: 50%;}
    .price_block:nth-child(odd) {border-right: 1px solid transparent;}
    .price_block:nth-child(3) {clear: both;}
    .price_block:nth-child(odd):hover {border: 0 none;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px){
    .price_block {width: 25%;}
    .price_block {border-right: 1px solid transparent; border-bottom: 0 none;}
    .price_block:last-child {border-right: 0 none;}
    .price_block:hover {border: 0 none;}
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="pricing_table">
<li class="price_block">
        <h3>Pricing Table</h3>

<div class="price">
            <div class="price_figure">
                <span class="price_number">$39.99</span>
                <span class="price_tenure">Only</span>
            </div>

</div>
<ul class="features">
<li>Features 1</li>
<li>Features 2</li>
<li>Features 3</li>
<li>Features 4</li>
<li>Features 5</li>
</ul>
<div class="footer">
            <a class="action_button" href="http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=7860351751400882510#">Buy Now</a>

        </div>
</li>

</ul>

<ul class="pricing_table">
<li class="price_block">
        <h3>Pricing Table</h3>

<div class="price">
            <div class="price_figure">
                <span class="price_number">$39.99</span>
                <span class="price_tenure">Only</span>
            </div>

</div>
<ul class="features">
<li>Features 1</li>
<li>Features 2</li>
<li>Features 3</li>
<li>Features 4</li>
<li>Features 5</li>
</ul>
<div class="footer">
            <a class="action_button" href="http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=7860351751400882510#">Buy Now</a>

        </div>
</li>

</ul>
<ul class="pricing_table">
<li class="price_block">
        <h3>Pricing Table</h3>

<div class="price">
            <div class="price_figure">
                <span class="price_number">$39.99</span>
                <span class="price_tenure">Only</span>
            </div>

</div>
<ul class="features">
<li>Features 1</li>
<li>Features 2</li>
<li>Features 3</li>
<li>Features 4</li>
<li>Features 5</li>
</ul>
<div class="footer">
            <a class="action_button" href="http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=7860351751400882510#">Buy Now</a>

        </div>
</li>

</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is this? Is this a _do your work_-service?

Comment: This is not "fix my code" website. You need to explain the problem clearly, and include only the most important code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place all of your `li` in one `ul` as done below

```
<ul class="pricing_table">
<li class="price_block">
        <h3>Pricing Table</h3>

<div class="price">
            <div class="price_figure">
                <span class="price_number">$39.99</span>
                <span class="price_tenure">Only</span>
            </div>

</div>
<ul class="features">
<li>Features 1</li>
<li>Features 2</li>
<li>Features 3</li>
<li>Features 4</li>
<li>Features 5</li>
</ul>
<div class="footer">
            <a class="action_button" href="http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=7860351751400882510#">Buy Now</a>

        </div>
</li>


<li class="price_block">
        <h3>Pricing Table</h3>

<div class="price">
            <div class="price_figure">
                <span class="price_number">$39.99</span>
                <span class="price_tenure">Only</span>
            </div>

</div>
<ul class="features">
<li>Features 1</li>
<li>Features 2</li>
<li>Features 3</li>
<li>Features 4</li>
<li>Features 5</li>
</ul>
<div class="footer">
            <a class="action_button" href="http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=7860351751400882510#">Buy Now</a>

        </div>
</li>


<li class="price_block">
        <h3>Pricing Table</h3>

<div class="price">
            <div class="price_figure">
                <span class="price_number">$39.99</span>
                <span class="price_tenure">Only</span>
            </div>

</div>
<ul class="features">
<li>Features 1</li>
<li>Features 2</li>
<li>Features 3</li>
<li>Features 4</li>
<li>Features 5</li>
</ul>
<div class="footer">
            <a class="action_button" href="http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=7860351751400882510#">Buy Now</a>

        </div>
</li>

</ul>
```

Fiddle is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Fehs3/1/)

Comment: Dear Usman, Thank you so much for fixing my code. Wish you a happy new year 2014! Thanks again for your time!